# Android BottomNavigationView items showing without text also layout does not hiding on scroll

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Hello Guys I have implemented `design library` `BottomNavigationView`. Its works perfectly but I don't know why my menu icon are not showing with text also I want  it to hide with scroll down such as `Floating Action Button`. But I didn't find any way to do that. I read [Developers Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) but i did not find any solution for my problem.

> **Here is my output**- Item Showing only text which is not enabled

[image]

> **Expected Output**- Every item should be with image and text

[image]

> **Here is my xml code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_color_state_list"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_color_state_list"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

> **nav_color_state_list.xml drawable Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/textColorSecondary" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

> **bottom_navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_black_36dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_notification"
        android:title="Notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_alert_black_36dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_call"
        android:title="Call"
        android:icon="@drawable/comment_black_36dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_more"
        android:title="More"
        android:icon="@drawable/more_horiz_black_36dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>>
   </menu>
```

Comment: I have also stucked in the same way as your question..Could u please give the suggestion on it..I want to use only BottomNavigationView, not any third party library

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha found the solution but my question has marked duplicate... so i can't post the solution here..

Comment: oh...Can u plz give me a suggestion on it?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i have posted 2 problem which one you facing

Comment: Right now..I want to create the divider between the items and size of image should be large..Is there any way for it??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha go for external libraries then... i can add dividers but cannot large the image size

Comment: Plz suggest me suggestion for the external library for it...And how can we add the divider on it..plz help

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140077/7130121

Comment: Thanks for urs valueable input..Bro i just want to draw the separate line "|" between the item.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943416/remove-bottom-navigation-view-text-in-android

Answer (score 11):

I use this library, it's an excellent extension!

https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

> BottomNavigationViewEx bnve = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bnve);
>
> bnve.enableAnimation(false);
>
> bnve.enableShiftingMode(false);
>
> bnve.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
>
> bnve.setIconSize(widthDp, heightDp);
>
> bnve.setTextSize(sp);

Comment: Nice library will be used in future...