# How to add dividers in Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, menuitem, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to add divider in menu items of **BottomNavigationView**

All items are showing **horizontally** in the bottom but I'm not able to add dividers into it.

Bottom Navigation View xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```

And bottom_nav_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_family"
    android:checked="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/family"
    android:title="@string/family" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_me"
    android:checked="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/me"
    android:title="@string/me" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_blank"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:title="" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_event"
    android:checked="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/event"
    android:title="@string/event" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_more"
    android:checked="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/more"
    android:title="@string/more" />
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: try to put every menu item in individual group

Comment: tried but it gave me error in xml for inflating

Answer (score 12, accepted):

create a drawable **item_bg.xml** like this,

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#F4F4F4" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#EAEAEA" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then add it to NavigationView as **app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_bg"**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:focusable="false"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_bg"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I have a question, whenever I am using the divider, I get at least one item having border with screen end. I want to reduce this gap. Can you tell me how can I do that? @ShutterSoul

Answer (score 0):

If someone still interested to do that despite it is not recommended.
You can achieve that programmatically to avoid having a divider at the end of the screen like the accepted solution.

```
 val bottomNavigationMenuView = (binding.navView[0] as BottomNavigationMenuView)
    if (bottomNavigationMenuView.isNotEmpty()) {
                  bottomNavigationMenuView[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_view_divider)
        bottomNavigationMenuView[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_view_divider)
        bottomNavigationMenuView[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_view_divider)

    }
```

Note: you will lose the ripple effect in the bottom view navigation when clicking on the item.

Answer (score -4):

Try this way...

```
BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
NavigationMenuView navMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) mBottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
navMenuView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: another option is you need to set select and unselect drawable and bind drawable in menu

Comment: Your answer is not valid. @AnshulTyagi is using BottomNavigationView and it has no methods to addItemDecoration.