# How to add divider in the bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

How can I add a divider in the Bottom Navigation view?
Basically a separator between the icons

Thank you

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140077/7666442 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview

Comment: Yes I did, first one does not work. No idea why it is accepted answer. Second one is for navigation view not bottom navigation. You can't do groups for bottom navogation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, the bottom navigation view has been created to match/follow Material Design guidelines and dividers are not supposed to be part of bottom navigation.
https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a divider between items something like that.

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        style="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/item_bg"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="0.8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/textview_black">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>


    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```