# Divider for BottomNavigationView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can I provide a divider for BottomNavigationView in Android? I need this tiny line between Home and Settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a background for the *BottomNavigationView* as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140077/6287910). If you already have a background and since *BottomNavigationView* is a *FrameLayout*, you could add a divider as follows:

**navigation_divider.xml**

```
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#E91E63" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu">

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_divider" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

You will, of course, need an even number of selections in the menu.