# How can I make BottomNavigationView have a certain background color in Android Java?

Tags: android, xml

I  have a layout for my app that has an action bar with a raspberry background. I also have a BottomNavigationView layout in the same layout. I need the bottom navigation view to have the same color as the action bar. The action bar uses the following theme in my styles file.

```
<style name="RaspBerry" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#E30B5C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#E30B5C</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The navigation view that I desire to style with the above theme is below. I wish the background color to be raspberry and the text *color* be white when selected and grey when unselected. How can I achieve this with XML?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawable_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"/>
```

Some answers do exist on the site, but I got confused implementing the samples as some used folders that are deprecated, like the colors folder.

Comment: You can have one custom drawable for background and one drawable for text color. I have done many times. And for reference follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140077/2404262

Comment: The link you shared has an answer for bottom navigation view divider, do they do the same thing?

Comment: same logic will be applied for background also.

Comment: I used the code, I cannot see the bottom navigation item texts until I select one of them