# android- support library BottomNavigationView not showing titles

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-bottomnav

I'm using android support design widget BottomNavigationView for making my bottom navigation items. this is the result of the job :
[image]

it has 2 problems , first it doesn't show the titles under the items, the second problem I want the items to fill the with , I don't want to have free space on the navigation ,I just want them to fill the space and divide the space between items.

this is my menu code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="ارتباط" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_history"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="سوابق خرید" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item3"
        android:icon="@drawable/sabad"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="سبد خرید" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item4"
        android:icon="@drawable/market2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="فروشگاه" />

</menu>
```

this is the xml code :

```
` <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.truiton.bottomnavigation.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="#fff"
            app:itemTextColor="#F2F2F4"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"/>
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

**Update** for design support library 28.0.0

uses `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` in your xml.

**Old answer** is a workaround for support library below 28.0.0

Your first problem, from the guideline [Bottom navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style)

- "if there are four or five actions, display inactive views as icons only"

for solution check this [Android BottomNavigationView items showing without text also layout does not hiding on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246928/android-bottomnavigationview-items-showing-without-text-also-layout-does-not-hid)

Comment: It's strange google themselves don't honour these guidelines. Play Newsstand and Youtube app both have four actions and they show icons and title on all the action views.

Answer (score 4):

To enable titles under the items use this trick. In your BottomNavigationView set parametr labelVisibilityMode to "labeled".

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    **app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"**
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

There are several types of title visibility:

- labeled (will keep all labels visible.)
- unlabeled (will show only icon)
- selected (will only show the label for the selected item and shift items)
- auto (will choose labeled or selected based on the number of items we have labeled for 1–3 items and selected for 3+ items)

Answer (score -1):

Two behaviors (not problems) are default behaviors. If i understood you correctly by "free space", this space is created by shifting animation that's a behavior of **BottomNavigationView**.
You can override **onLayout** method of **BottomNavigationView** class then you can use the extended tag to avoiding these two. This approach also sets custom font family for BottomNavigationView if you want.

```
public final class ExtendedBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView{
    private final Context context;
    private Typeface fontFace = null;

    public ExtendedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final ViewGroup bottomMenu = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
        final int bottomMenuChildCount = bottomMenu.getChildCount();
        BottomNavigationItemView item;
        View itemTitle;
        Field shiftingMode;

        if(fontFace == null){
            fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.VazirBold));
        }
        try {
            //if you want to disable shiftingMode:
            //shiftingMode is a private member variable so you have to get access to it like this:
            shiftingMode = bottomMenu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(bottomMenu, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        //for changing font face of item titles.
        for(int i=0; i<bottomMenuChildCount; i++){
            item = (BottomNavigationItemView)bottomMenu.getChildAt(i);
            //this shows all titles of items
            item.setChecked(true);
            //every BottomNavigationItemView has two children, first is an itemIcon and second is an itemTitle
            itemTitle = item.getChildAt(1);
            //every itemTitle has two children, first is a smallLabel and second is a largeLabel. these two are type of AppCompatTextView
            ((TextView)((BaselineLayout) itemTitle).getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView)((BaselineLayout) itemTitle).getChildAt(1)).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<your.package.name.ExtendedBottomNavigationView android:id="@id/bottomMenu" style="@style/bottomMenu"/>
```